# How to switch Office Addin from inactive to active?

Tags: c#, registry, vsto, office-addins, visio

I have an issue with certain one computer only.
I can't switch the Addin to active.
In addition, the installation of the Addin does not create folder/key in the Registry with LoadBehavior velue, so, i can't change it from the Registry. Do you know why the Registry folder/key is not create?

Comment: Another Addin works fine on the same computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have some issues with the add-in installer. I'd suggest making sure that you did all the steps described in the [Deploy an Office solution by using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019) article if you are using MSI and [Deploy an Office solution by using ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-clickonce?view=vs-2019) in case of ClickOnce.

You can use the event viewer in Windows to see exception messages that are captured by the Visual Studio Tools for Office runtime when you install or uninstall Office solutions. You can use these messages from the event logger to resolve installation and deployment problems. Read more about that in the [Troubleshoot Office solution deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/troubleshooting-office-solution-deployment?view=vs-2019) article.

Be aware, Microsoft Office applications can disable VSTO Add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your VSTO Add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your VSTO Add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the `Startup` event handler in your VSTO Add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable a VSTO Add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled VSTO Add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the VSTO Add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the VSTO Add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the VSTO Add-in again.

Comment: Do you have some idea why the same Addin works fine for few PCs and dont work fine on certain PC?

Comment: It depends on the following things: how installer finished its work, whether all prerequisites were installed and etc.